# merge git original branch master into fork master

Tags: git, github

I've code my webapp client. I've 2 branch: master to production and develop to test and staging.
Now I have to separate my project into 2 independent version, however some bugs of original version remains into each repo (original and fatch), so I will make some edit double time. There is any way to marge master branch of original repo into master branch of forked repo?
Or have you a more gently solution for this use case?

Thanks

Comment: This is literally the exact reason for using a "fork". You set up multiple remotes and you can merge to and from each of them

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do it using Github interface. You should go to the original project (the one you've forked) and click in the **New Pull Request** button. Then you should click in the **compare across forks** link that appears under the Compare changes title. After doing that you should be able to select you fork as the origin of the new PR.

Here is a more detailed guide: https://help.github.com/articles/creating-a-pull-request-from-a-fork/